# How To Test a Grunt Plugin

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, mocha.js

I'm creating my first ever Grunt Plugin. I would really like to practice testing my plugin as I develop. I've selected mocha as my testing framework, as it seems popular, and setup my gruntfile to automatically watch when test files are altered and run them. This all looks good.

But, I've not found a lot of documentation on how to actually test a Grunt Plugin. I've looked at code of about a dozen different grunt plugins, especially the contrib ones, and they don't make a lot of sense to me.

As I try to test my code I'm trying to break things down into very specific functions. So, here is the basic structure of a plugin, with a function in it.

```
'use strict';

function testOutsideOfTask(){
  return "i am outside";
}

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerMultiTask('example_task', 'I do a thing.', function() {

    function testInsideOfTask(){
      return "i am inside";
    }

  });

};
```

I've included a couple of methods just explicitly to make sure my testing is working, and it's not. Neither of these methods seem to be accessible... How could I access both of them for testing? Here is the mocha test as I have it.

```
var grunt = require('grunt');
var assert = require("assert");

describe('testOutsideOfTask', function() {
  it('do something', function() {
    assert.equal("i am outside", testOutsideOfTask());
  });
});

describe('testInsideOfTask', function() {
  it('do something', function() {
    assert.equal("i am inside", testInsideOfTask());
  });
});
```

They both return something like this. So, somehow it just can't access the functions, however, when I look at other testing examples, they don't seem to specifically require the file that is being tested... For example https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean/blob/master/test/clean_test.js

```
1) testOutsideOfTask should do something:
ReferenceError: testOutsideOfTask is not defined
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm curious - what is your grunt plugin going to do? (off topic, I know)

Comment: My plugin is going to ping google and bing with sitemap urls. Very very simple, but I want to learn how to do it correctly, with tests :)

Comment: The reason you cant find your functions is because you need to `require` the file with that function. You will also need to export it through the modules definition. `p=require('myplugin');p.outsideFunction()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to be testing functionality, ideally. Your Grunt plugin should end up as a wrapper around more abstract methods that do what you want but not necessarily tied to how Grunt works; then for the actual plugin you run those methods on each file, log some output etc. Something like this:

```
var lib = require('./lib.js');

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerMultiTask('test', function() {
        lib.doSomeMethod();
        grunt.log.ok('Something happened');
    });
}
```

So in that pseudo code you would want to actually test the `doSomeMethod` function and not that Grunt registered a task or logged to the CLI. That's already well tested.

A lot of Grunt plugins work in this way, in fact many are wrappers around existing node modules. For example, grunt-recess is a wrapper of twitter/recess:

- https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-recess
- https://github.com/twitter/recess

One of my own modules is more Grunt specific, but the tests for that focus on the actual functionality of the module. You can have a look at that here:

https://github.com/ben-eb/grunt-available-tasks/blob/master/test/lib/filterTasks.test.js

I'm also testing with Mocha. I'd recommend that you use [grunt-mocha-test](https://github.com/pghalliday/grunt-mocha-test) to run your tests through Grunt (as well as JSHint and others).

Comment: Great, that makes some sense. I'm going to give this a shot. A couple of follow ups to your side notes:

- For some reason I was drawn to grunt-mocha-test, so that's what i selected. Thanks for mentioning that.
- I use VIM with a jshint plugin... is there some advantage to switching to a jshint grunt task?

P.S. I will mark your answer the moment I get it working. Thanks again!

Comment: There's some synergy with Grunt's watch task and JSHint + Mocha, but it's not really necessary if it's built in to your editor; that being said, if you plan on open sourcing then having that setup is better for contributors because then everyone is using the same setup for linting. Some people are stricter than others with custom rules, but I guess that's really a preference thing. It doesn't really hurt to use both! :-)

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question if you are looking for test coverage...